# Sort a hash with key as month date with many values for the same month

Tags: ruby, date, hash

I create a hash with months as keys and timelaps as values

```
biens_delai[bien_date.mon] = b.delai
```

I get this result without month parsing

```
{Wed, 18 Jan 2017=>3.0, Sat, 25 Feb 2017=>2.0, Fri, 17 Mar 2017=>3.0, Sat, 25 Mar 2017=>5.0, Tue, 18 Apr 2017=>2.0, Thu, 29 Jun 2017=>2.0}
```

In March i have 2 values but when i parse by month i get the most high value and i want a addition of 2 values for March not the most high

```
  {1=>3.0, 2=>2.0, 3=>5.0, 4=>2.0, 6=>2.0}
```

Comment: There is neither code nor question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the high value which you are getting, the values are getting overwritten, try the following

```
biens_delai[bien_date.mon] = biens_delai[bien_date.mon].to_f + b.delai
```

Comment: Thanks its what i looking for